# store image into isolated storage in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Basically I am using Visual Studio/Expression Blend to do my app. Its works as in the user can select the picture that he/she wants to edit and after editing the user just had to click the save button and the edited image will be save in isolated storage but I just could not command the save button to save the image into the isolated storage so hope someone will help me with it with some sample codes thanks a lot in advance.

I tried with the code below but when I press the save button there's a null reference error. My thinking is that when you press save, the app does not know which image to save into the isolated storage and not really sure my thinking is right. Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks a lot.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String tempJPEG = "TempJPEG";

    var myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
    if (myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG))
    {
        myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
    }

    IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG);

    Uri uri = new Uri("TestImage.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
    StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None; 
    bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

    Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
    myFileStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the working version of the code

```
private void saveButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (isf.FileExists("myImage.jpg"))
                isf.DeleteFile("myImage.jpg");
            using (var isfs = isf.CreateFile("myImage.jpg"))
            {
                var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(myImageElement,
                                myImageElement.RenderTransform);
                bmp.SaveJpeg(isfs, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Here `myImageElement` is the Image Element in which you display the image.

Comment: Hi,your this code is put under the save button? means after you click the save button the image will store into the isolated storage?and by the way image object is what?

Comment: You can place the code wherever you want, in your case as you want to save the image, you can place it in the ClickEvent Handler of the button. By [Image objet] i mean the Image Element which you are using to display the image

Comment: I tired with that but theres still error. 
bi.SetSource(pic); 
where do you declare your (pic)?

Comment: i posted my code.you can have a look of it and theres also another error when i click the button.thanks alot

Comment: ok i will give it a try if theres any problem i will keep u posted thanks alot

Comment: sorry for the trouble I am still new to windows phone 7 app so dont mind give me an example of myImageElement? i really not sure what it is .thanks.is it the image name or other thing?

Comment: The image element is the Image element you create in your XAML. Ex:-<Image x:name="myImageElement" width="200" height="200"/>. If you are using Blend then you can just rename the Image element which you are using to display your image, in the elements panel located in the bottom-left corner of Blend.

Comment: thanks for the help.Another issue is the codes works for variety of images? and at the same time when i press save button the image will be show on the another page

Comment: Please clarify what u mean by,"image will be show on the another page"

Comment: the code now only able to save 1 image into isolated storage.is it able to save more than 1 image into the isolated storage?

Comment: @user801456 First clarify me whether you want to save image which is being displayed or which is included in your resource folder...

Comment: @user801456 First clarify me whether you want to save image which is being displayed or which is included in your resource folder...

Comment: there are variety of images at gallery which i can choose to edit and the edited ones will be save in isolated storage.now the codes works for one image which the app will overlap and save the latest image in isolated storage.so now how could i save more than 1 image in isolated storage

Comment: Basically u need to save the edited image which is displayed in ur Image element. So whenever you are done editing, call the function to save the image which is being displayed

Comment: if (isf.FileExists("myImage.jpg"))
                        
isf.DeleteFile("myImage.jpg");

cuz theres a if statement so whenever u save a edited image it will be call as myImage.jpg and so it will replaced with the latest

Comment: Just change the image name to whatever you want everytime you save a new image... or create a GUID for each image

Comment: now i store the image as different name.and i could be able to retrieve only 1 image so how could i retrieve many images and whats the image file name ?

Comment: Hi, I tried to save many images but it still could not work. The code that u provided works for an image so dont mind can help me saving many images in isolated.Really appreciate if you could help me make adjustment to the code that you provided is able to works for saving more than 1 image into isolated storage.Thanks