# save image into isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [store image into isolated storage in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372422/store-image-into-isolated-storage-in-windows-phone-7)

I am using Visual Studio/Expression Blend to create my app for windows phone 7. The user should be able to select a  picture that he/she wants to edit and after editing, the user can click a "save" button and the specific edited image will be saved in isolated storage. But I'm having trouble saving the image to Isolated Storage from the button click event.

Does anyone have a code example of how this can be achieved? Thanks!

My codes for the button :

```
using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()) 

{ 

var bi = new BitmapImage(); bi.SetSource(pic); 

var wb = new WriteableBitmap(lion.jpg,lion.jpg.RenderTransform); 

using (var isoFileStream = isoStore.CreateFile("somepic.jpg")) 

{ 

var width = wb.PixelWidth; 

var height = wb.PixelHeight;

Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, isoFileStream, width, height, 0, 100); 

 } 
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the following link http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-XML-files-using-XmlWriter

Comment: It would be helpful to see your code thus far?

Comment: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6373702/edit) code into the question. You'll be able to format it correctly so it'll be much easier to read.

Answer (score 7):

To save an image to IsolatedStorage from a PhotoChooserTask, use this (the `e` object in the task callback holds the stream):

```
public static void SaveImage(Stream imageStream, string fileName, int orientation, int quality)
{
    using (var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        if (isolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            isolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);

        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(imageStream);

        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
        wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, orientation, quality);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```