# Navigate to a page when EventHandler compelete?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1

So I am trying to do a very simple thing in WP7 like:

A button in MainPage will launch camera, and when camera successfully take a picture, I want to pass the picture to SecondPage and launch it.

Here's my code:

Within the MainPage constructor, I initialize the camera task and set the delegate:

`camTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(camTask_Completed);`

Then I implemented the `camTask_Completed`

```
 void camTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        
        img = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

The application will run without error until after I pressed "accept" after I took the picture.

The exception says:

`Exception  {"Navigation is not allowed when the task is not in the foreground."}   System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}`

Which I understand is that I shouldn't launch the SecondPage within the `camTask_Completed` method.

Then my question is: How to launch another page on the result of EventHandler?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** (For answer to this sub-question, please refer to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935459/navigate-to-a-page-when-eventhandler-compelete/12935907#comment17532242_12935907) in this page)

I found another error right after I click the button(to launch the camera):

It throw an exception said:

`"Type 'System.Windows.Media.Transform' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute."`

Where could I serialize the `Transform` stuff?

I did some search on Google and found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharpgeneral/thread/2b0a624e-17cc-4c0d-936c-aa00d3a5256e):

> Found the answer, the error actually suggests it too :)
>
> [DataContract]
>
> [KnownType(typeof(System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform))]

Seemed it can resolve this problem, but where should I put these lines?

This is my code on MainPage to pass the image to SecondPage, `img` is a `WriteableBitmap`:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        var brush = new ImageBrush();
        brush.ImageSource = img;
        PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["bkg"] = brush;
    }
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps You should try to use the dispatcher:

```
activePage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
     () => NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)));
```

This works in MetroApps.

Comment: thx for your quick response, the error is, I think, because of the `camTask_Completed` is a method launched from camera, thus the MainPage is not in foreground so cannot do dispatcher stuff.

Comment: The problem is that only the foreground thread can access the UI.
try this:
 void camTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        img = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto);

        mainpage.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
     () => NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)));
    }

Comment: thx mate, I tried ur method and also I found another error, please refer to my updated question, thanx. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's a known issue with the CameraCaptureTask.
Here is the workaround that I use:

```
    void OnCameraCaptureTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult args)
    {
        //Delay navigation until the first navigated event
        NavigationService.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(navigateCompleted);
    }

    void navigateCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do the delayed navigation from the main page
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        NavigationService.Navigated -= new NavigatedEventHandler(navigateCompleted);
    }
```

Comment: I think it is another problem. It seems like you are trying to serializing an object. Are you saving objects states? `SolidColorBrush` has a property named `Transform` of type `Transform`. If it's that, you should serialize the Color instead.

Comment: yeah, i'm trying to pass the camera photo to a canvas on the second page and set it as `canvas.background`

Comment: In that case, you should save the resulting image into the IsolatedStorage and read it later on your 2nd page. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373702/save-image-into-isolated-storage