# Save screenshot in isolated storage using key-value pairs

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am developing app for windows phone 7,there i am trying to save screenshot in isolated storage(By creating folder) using key-value pairs, so that i can retrieve all images one by one using their keys,
please help.
Thank you..

Comment: You can't do that. But you can do another thing that is useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372422/store-image-into-isolated-storage-in-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use KeyValuePair? If you want to retrieve images one by one using their key, you can store the images in set of arrays and retrieve the image using the index.

KeyValuePair is only used when you retrieving the value using Key and by default, KeyValuePair make type conversions automatically( Which is the major difference from Dictionary) and performs the operation.

With the reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372422/store-image-into-isolated-storage-in-windows-phone-7), i tried to bring out the solution for your question and here is my answer.

```
int i = 0;
private void saveButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            using (var isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                WriteableBitmap[] count = new WriteableBitmap[10]; // Size 10 for sample
                if (isf.FileExists("myImage.jpg"))
                    isf.DeleteFile("myImage.jpg");
                using (var isfs = isf.CreateFile("myImage.jpg"))
                {
                    var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(myImageElement,
                                    myImageElement.RenderTransform);
                    bmp.SaveJpeg(isfs, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                    count[i] = bmp;
                    i +=1; // Save your count value else it takes null when you save next image.
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```